# I am new to jsp and google app engine getting this error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

This is my JSP File. It has 3 text fields and a submit button..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
<body>
   <form action="buttontoserv" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br>        
    <input type="text" name="group"/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">            
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ButtontoServ</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pack.exp.ButtontoServServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ButtontoServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/buttontoserv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is the servlet under pack.exp package with file name ButtontoServServlet.java

```
package pack.exp;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtontoServServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String group = request.getParameter("group");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    System.out.println("Name :"+ name);
    System.out.println("group :"+ group);
    System.out.println("pass :"+ pass);
    }
}
```

When I am deploying it to the google app engineit is throwing this error
"Error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"

I also tried on tomcat and the error says
"HTTPO 405 Method not allowed. The website cannot display the page HTTP 405
 Most likely cause: •The website has a programming error."

Comment: add a forward slash in <form action="/buttontoserv" method="post">

Comment: @ jsjunkie
getting the same error.

Comment: This doesn't get problem at my Tomcat server. This may be the issue of google-app-engine.

Comment: @ Masud
It is giving error in my tomcat. My tomcat is working fine with other programs.

Comment: please post the url that you are seeing in your browser once you click the submit button. You can mask the i.p. I want to see the URL from your context path onwards.

Comment: @ jsjunkie
I am not able to see the jsp page aswell. After I click on my Available servlet on app engine after deployment i get the error..
http://1.shanxapp.appspot.com/
http://1.shanxapp.appspot.com/buttontoserv

Answer (score 1):

As your servlet has only `doPost` method. So, you can't get access the servlet with URL. Your URL should be for JSP page where `action="buttontoserv"` is assigned. When you click the submit button of JSP page than it will forwarded to `/buttontoserv` servlet.

To solve your problem, you should include a `doGet` method on Servlet or forward to Servlet with form submit from JSP page.

```
public class ButtontoServServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String group = request.getParameter("group");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    System.out.println("Name :"+ name);
    System.out.println("group :"+ group);
    System.out.println("pass :"+ pass);

    }    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shanx, The best way is to keep both doGet & doPost and call here common `processRequest(request, response);` method. I have updated answer with Servlet code.

Comment: @Shanx, It show blank page because, nothing is written on Servlet.

Comment: @  Masud
But sir why it is not showing the jsp page with 3 textfields and a button

Comment: For your JSP, you should use another link, like http://1.shanxapp.appspot.com/MyJSP.jsp, Here MyJSP.jsp is JSP page of web folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you type the url to the jsp file instead of the servlet. Also try overriding the doGet method too like:

```
protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
         doPost(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: @ Asim
where to type the url of the jsp file?

Comment: I have added the doGet func as well . But still the same problm